# Make main args longer (name change linux)

Tags: c, linux

In linux I can modify `int main(int argc, char*argv[])` contents to change what is shown in `ps`. So far I had no problems however in one case I want to make it longer by including a GUID or some kind of id. In that case I found it will not work if the arguments weren't long enough to hold it. Basically I want to add text so when a user runs `ps` looking at multiple app instance would be more friendly.

How would I make the arguments longer so I can add text to be shown in `ps`?

Comment: @zneak yes. Mostly bc if the args is say 8 letters there isn't enough space for the GUID so it just does its own thing (looks like scraps all args)

Comment: Your edit made it clearer.

Comment: Is it an issue of `ps`'s display not being wide enough, or is something else at play?

Answer (score 1):

Someone may have to double-check, but in the other ABIs that I know (Mac OS 9, Mac OS X), `argv` strings are located at the top of the stack, before the entry point's frame. (This could be easily verified with gdb by looking up the address of `&argv[0]` and comparing it with another stack variable's address.)

Stack allocations typically being non-resizable, you are most likely confined to whatever space the original arguments took.

One possibility for you could be to pass your program a parameter called something like `--thirthy-characters-long-guid` and replace that parameter with a GUID at runtime if it is present.

Comment: Come to think of it I could just execute another instance of my app with a longer argument or the correct ones. I don't remember from the top of my head the correct call to execute an app. I don't mind if it is a child process or a separate one. Fork wouldn't work

Comment: If this is C, you're most likely looking for a function from the `execve` family. You shouldn't need to fork given your use case.